# I can't get Facebook to scrape links I post to my blog

Tags: facebook, image, hyperlink, blogger, scrape

None of the right pictures show up when I post a link on Facebook to a blog post I've made. I've tried to add og tags to all sorts of things in my blog code and nothing has worked. Help!

I tried the linter, and this is what I get. Inferred Property:  The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Do I have to start adding og tags to every single post?

http://michelleglauser.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

When you post/share a link on facebook the link has a url, facebook need to have the og tags for each url.

For example http://michelleglauser.blogspot.com and http://michelleglauser.blogspot.com/2012/04/links-to-love-week-14-2012.html are two different urls and each has to have og tags if you want to control the way facebook presents them.

I took a look at the html code of your site and it seems like you did in fact provided with og:title, og:type and og:url but the og:image and og:description are commented out for some reason, that is they look like this in the code:

```
<!--
/*
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s191.photobucket.com/albums/z72/MichemilyG/Blog/?action=view&current=Circles-and-Dots-and-Other-Distractions-Michelle-Glauser-Blog-Header-Flat.jpg"/>
<link rel="http://s191.photobucket.com/albums/z72/MichemilyG/Blog/?action=view&current=Circles-and-Dots-and-Other-Distractions-Michelle-Glauser-Blog-Header-Flat.jpg" href="thumbnail_image" / >
<meta property="fb:title" content="Circles and Dots and Other Distractions"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Michelle Glauser"/>
...
```

You need to put those tags with the rest of the og tags.

Comment: I'm not sure what either of you are saying. Faris, I have to change the code for every single post? Nitzan, what is "commented out"? What should the code look like, if not like that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You don't have to produce different "code" for different pages, but it only makes sense that you do. Since each post of yours probably has a different title and description? maybe a different image that is associated with it? As for the "commented out", [HTML Comment](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) tells the parser (and browser) to "not mind" anything in between those tags, and you have some code there which is just ignored, some of it is open graph tags which are "needed" and therefor you need to take out of the comments tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I just implemented on a wordpress site I was developing (blogger is a bit different ofc). Basically, it checks to see if the current page you are on has an associated hero image. If if does, it uses that hero image. If it doesn't, it uses the logo image. That way, when I 'like' one of my blog posts (even from the front page, and not from the blog post page itself), facebook pings that url and looks for associated og:image and og:description tags.

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    $fb_image = ui::getImage(290, 121, "align left");
    if(!$fb_image){
        $fb_image = ui::logo();
    }
?>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php ui::title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $fb_image ?>"/>
```

this goes in the 'head' section of every page btw